# Change in the date and time after date_format in mysql

Tags: mysql

I inserted  `now()` in a mysql table column . I tried to convert the `timestamp(now())` using `date_format` while retrieving. But it is showing different value than what i inserted.

inserted  : `2012-08-09 01:45:11`

```
date_format(creation_date,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%m %p') : 09-08-2012 01:08 AM
```

I set `set time_zone:'+05:30'`

May i know why it is showing like this?

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake :(
need to use `date_format(creation_date,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p')`